# Redirect only FQDN and www. to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Currently I have the following RewriteRules in place to redirect users to HTTPS:

```
# Force all request to HTTPS URLs                                                    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https                                         
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=302,L]
```

It redirects all traffic though and I would like it to only do so for FQDN and www. sudomain.

So redirect:

- example.org
- www.example.org

Examples not to be redirected:

- example.example.org
- www.example.example.org
- blog.example.org

What `RewriteCond` statements do I need to add to make this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this condition: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.org$ [NC]`.
This will match both `example.org` and `www.example.org` only.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302,L]
```

---

EDIT: avoid using domain name in rules (this means using exceptions subdomains)

```
RewriteEngine On

# if subdomain exception do nothing
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example|www\.example|blog)\. [NC]
RewriteRule . - [L]

# if we reach here, that means we have www.example.org or example.org so redirect if not https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Is there anyway of doing this without hard coding the domain?

Comment: Well nothing is impossible. Yes it can be done the way you want but it would complicate a little more the code. Why would you avoid to hard code the domain ? Is there any reason ?

Comment: It will appear as part of a base installation for a solution that is to be deployed by various parties across varying hardware/OS so it would be nice to be able to remove the step of editing this.

Comment: In that case, we should take the problem in reverse. I mean, we'll replace domain check by exceptions-to-be-redirect check. You can see my edited answer about it